# Nginx send all connections to server A before going to Server B before going to server C..etc

Tags: nginx, websocket, backend, load-balancing, connection-pooling

I am using nginx to balance connections to backend tcp servers using the stream directive. I have two separate questions in regards to balancing the connections as the default algorithms don't seem to be good enough.

- Is it possible to load balance in a way that you first max out connections on Server A before moving on to Server B. Once B is maxed then move on to server C?
- Is it possible to load balance in a way that you send the first 50 connections to server A, then the next 50 to server B. Once both have reached 50 repeat the process again for Server A and server B in a cycle until both have reached max load?

  upstream tcpServerSocket {
  server 127.0.0.1:9091;
  server 127.0.0.1:9092;
  }

  server {
  server 9090;
  proxy_pass tcpServerSocket;
  }

Currently I am using the algorithm choice of round robin which is not great for my use case. These are websockets if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Hash load balancing method as described in Nginx documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash

To use with Websocket, you can try implementing the example shared in this gist: https://gist.github.com/gihad/25b3c87f35b20b3d3bb6ad589ea42974

Comment: I'm guessing based on what you provided I would have to somehow programmatically figure out what id to use. That could mean standing up a whole nother socket server just to send the client an id for use then the client would send a second connection with the id. I was hoping the balancer could take some kind of custom balancing implementation instead of me telling the client to connect twice, once to a controller server to get an id then a second time to the actual server.

Comment: Basically what I want NGINX to do is the OPPOSITE of "least connections". I want it to route all traffic to the backend node with the most connections. If it is maxed out go to the next node with the most traffic. The alternative is to implement my own socket server that tells the browser  which node to go to and then expose all of my nodes to the internet serverA:9090, serverB:9091, serverC:9092 which doesn't seem right. At that point I wouldn't even need a load balancer.